# SQL SUM() function with parameters returned by query for each row

Tags: sql-server, database, join, sum

First of all, sorry for that weird title. Here is the thing:
I work for a online shop, which sells products on amazon. Since we sell sets of different items, it happens that we send the same item within multiple sets to amazon fba. To give out the total sum of one item in all sets, I wrote the following query:

```
SELECT
  SUM(nQuantity)
  AS [total]
FROM [amazon_fba]
INNER JOIN (SELECT
  [cArtNr]
FROM [tArtikel]
INNER JOIN (SELECT
  [kStueckliste]
FROM [tStueckliste]
WHERE [kArtikel] = (SELECT
  [kArtikel]
FROM [tArtikel]
WHERE [cHAN] = 12345)) [bar]
  ON [tArtikel].[kStueckliste] = [bar].[kStueckliste]) [foo]
  ON [amazon_fba].[cSellerSKU] = [foo].[cArtNr]
```

The `cHAN=12345` part is just used to pick one specific item for which we want to know the total number of items. This query itself works fine, so this is not the problem.

However, I also know that all products that are part of sets have `[tArtikel].[kStueckliste]=0`, which -in theory- makes identifying them pretty easy. Which got me to the idea, that I could use this query to instantly generate a list of all these products with their respective total, like:

```
kArtikel | total
=================
   01234 | 23
   56789 | 42
```

So basically I needed something like

```
foreach (
    select [kArtikel]
    from [tArtikel]
    where [tArtikel].[kStueckliste]=0
) do (
    < the query I made >
)
```

Thus I tried the following statement:

```
SELECT
  SUM(nQuantity)
  AS [total]
FROM [amazon_fba]
INNER JOIN (SELECT
  [cArtNr]
FROM [tArtikel]
INNER JOIN (SELECT
  [kStueckliste]
FROM [tStueckliste]
INNER JOIN (SELECT
  [kArtikel]
FROM [tArtikel]
WHERE [tArtikel].[tStueckliste] = 0) [baz]
  ON [tStueckliste].[kArtikel] = [baz].[kArtikel]) [bar]
  ON [tArtikel].[kStueckliste] = [bar].[kStueckliste]) [foo]
  ON [amazon_fba].[cSellerSKU] = [foo].[cArtNr]
```

This did not -as I hoped- return a list of sums, but instead gave me the total sum of all sums I wanted to create. 
Since I am pretty new to SQL (about two weeks in maybe), I have neither any idea what to do, nor where my mistake is, NOR what phrasing I should use to google my way around -thus that wierd Title of this post. So if anyone could help me with that and/or point me into the right direction I'd be really happy :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I write MySQL rather than SQL but I believe it's very similar other than a few functions and syntaxes. Here's what I think should work for you:

```
select am.cArtNr, sum(am.nQuantity) as total
from amazon_fba am
join tArtikel ar on ar.cArtNr=am.cArtNr
join tStueckliste st on st.kStueckliste=ar.kStueckliste
where ar.kStueckliste=0
group by am.cArtNr;
```

Adding the group by will do the split out by articles, but reducing the number of brackets (in this instance derived tables) will speed up the query provided you're using indexes. Again, this is how I would do it in MySQL, and the only other query language I have experience in is BigQuery which won't help here.